# How can I get an output from an endless recursive async function?

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a program for which I need an endless counter. For this I am using an async function, which recursivly calls itself over and over again. Since I can't ever return this method and I can't use an `out` parameter in an async function I am just writing the output into an outside variable. This feels very wrong to me though. Is there a better way to do this?

```
public abstract class SkateAI : IAgent
{
protected SkateAI(float movespeed)
{
    MoveSpeed = movespeed;
}

public float MoveSpeed;

protected Vector2 Position = new (0, 0);
protected float BetweenTicker;
protected float StartTime = 0;
protected PeriodicTimer timer = new(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1.0f));
protected bool _isUp;
protected bool _timerStarted;

public Vector2 GetPosition()
{
    return Position;
}

internal async Task TickBetweenTimer(float input, float speedFactor = 1)
{
    if (BetweenTicker >= input)
        _isUp = false;
    else if (BetweenTicker <= 0)
        _isUp = true;

    switch (_isUp)
    {
        case false:
            BetweenTicker -= 0.001f * MoveSpeed * speedFactor;
            break;
        default:
            BetweenTicker += 0.001f * MoveSpeed * speedFactor;
            break;
    }

    await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(CancellationToken.None);
    TickBetweenTimer(input, speedFactor);
}
```

Comment: Rather than using an async function you may want o consider using a Timer or Thread and then raise events with your output

Comment: To answer your original question: using a variable for communication in such case _might_ be fine, but you have more important things to worry about in this code.

Comment: I am still a novice programer. Any advice on the general code is also very much appreciated! @SergeyKudriavtsev

Comment: if it's an infinite recursion, you will run into an StackOverflowException at some point

Comment: @HaleJan Apologies, I meant to include it in my comment, but hit Enter too soon. First of all, your code will throw a StackOverflow exception fairly fast - due to unbound recursion. Second, creating a timer with 1ms resolution most likely wouldn't work in a way you expect it to work - the issue here is that the minimal actual timer resolution is defined by a system clock resolution, which is, depending on the OS, anything from 2-3ms to 20+ms.

Comment: I agree with the other comments, but purely riffing on your current code design: What exactly led you to think you need recursion with your chosen approach instead of just an endless iteration?

Comment: Lack of general coding knowledge probably. @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace I am rewriting it so a timer calls the method now instead of making it recursive. That should make it possible for me to just return the variable. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: How to report progress from async functions: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev if `WaitForNextTickAsync` is "real" async function (and not completely synchronous like `return Task.FromResult`) - this function will not overflow the stack despite unconditionally calling itself.

Comment: Using recursion sounds like a terrible idea. Assuming this is for some game, and you should probably have a game loop instead of a bunch of individual timers, this help to ensure everything in your game runs in a well defined, predictable order, on a single thread. But the correct way to do this would depend on the framework. Unity has a built in [game loop](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html). Winforms/Wpf might be done with timers, but are probably not ideal for real time games.

Comment: @evk Live and learn, thanks for the correction.

Comment: I think you can just set the start time in a variable then with some simple calculation (in a method) you can achieve to timer ticks and  everything you want. If you need the real time result put it in in a while loop